# Cut a list in 3 parts to speed up Async function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, .net-6.0

i have a linq expression which does the job:

```
var y = docs.ToList()
var res = y.Select(async b => await loadAgence(b.url))
           .Select(x => x.Result)
    :
    :
private async Task<BsonDocument? doc, int status, bool iSSucess) loadAgence(string url)
{
    var (docs, status, isSuccess) = await Helper.API_GetDocument(url);
    return (isSuccess ? docs : null, status, isSuccess)
}
```

> this job takes 3 minutes to execute 900 loops (900 Call API)

i would cut the collection in 3 parts, to divise by 3 the time lapse

```
var res1 = y.Skip(0).Take(300).Select(async b => await loadAgence(b.url))
            .Select(x => x.Result)
var res2 = y.Skip(300).Take(300)Select(async b => await loadAgence(b.url))
            .Select(x => x.Result)
var res3 = y.Skip(600).Take(300)Select(async b => await loadAgence(b.url))
            .Select(x => x.Result)
```

but of course each part is blocked,  how i could resolve this problem?

i have tried to use `WhenAll` with a list collection (res1 to res3)  but its waiting `IEnumerable<Task>`  and i have `List<IEnumerable<Task<BsonDocument? doc, int status, bool iSuccess)>>>`   so it refuses the cast..

is it possible to do that?

Comment: You should avoid using `.Result` and blocking in an async task without using await.

Comment: Does it work for you if you remove the last `Select`, and then do something like `await Task.WhenAll(res1, res2, res3)`? As long as all the tasks have the same generic arguments, it should work using [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-whenall-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-threading-tasks-task((-0))))))

Comment: Do you have considered to use [PLinq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq)?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)

Comment: Also, `res` in your example should have type `IEnumerable<Task<BsonDocument? doc, int status, bool iSSucess)>>`. So it should be usable with `WhenAll`. I'm not sure where you get your `List<IEnumerable<...>>` from.

Comment: thanks for your comments,  @julealgon the problem was to include `multiple IEnumerable<Task>` and the overload doesnt exist for that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but of course each part is blocked, how i could resolve this problem?

Because you use `.Select(x => x.Result)` for each part of `Task` list which means that the code will wait for each connection as same as synchronizing code.

If you want to use asynchronous code we might get `Task` or `Task` of List for this example we will get `IEnumerable<Task(BsonDocument? doc, int status, bool iSSucess)>>` from `res1`, `res2`,`res3`

```
var res1 = y.Skip(0).Take(300).Select(async b => await loadAgence(b.url));
var res2 = y.Skip(300).Take(300).Select(async b => await loadAgence(b.url));
var res3 = y.Skip(600).Take(300).Select(async b => await loadAgence(b.url));
```

Unfortunately [`Task.WhenAll`](https://Task.WhenAll) might not support multiple `IEnumerable<Task>` array parameters, so we can try to use `List<Task<(BsonDocument? doc, int status, bool iSSucess)>>` to append all of list in that then `Task.WhenAll`

```
var tasks = new List<Task<(BsonDocument? doc, int status, bool iSSucess)>>();   
tasks.AddRange(res1);   
tasks.AddRange(res2);   
tasks.AddRange(res3);  

var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem was in the way to include multiple `IEnumerable<Task>`  and , yes your answer gives the solution..!!

Comment: With this solution, i do not need to cut in multiple part...3 minutes to 18 sec...